# Change input and textarea background color when there's no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What's the recommended approach to change the `background color` of `input` and `textarea` when there's no value? Can this only be done on page load or can it be persistent? I prefer if it's persistent since I have a form that loads from callbacks.

I'm thinking JQuery would be best for this to affect this css:

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

I tried this, but only the textarea had the changes for some reason:

```
input[type="text"]:empty, textarea:empty {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

DevExpress input textbox:

```
<input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys"
 id="ctl00_ctl00_ASPxSplitter1_Content_ContentSplitter_MainContent_ASPxCallbackPanel1_ASPxFormLayout3_ASPxFormLayout3_E18_I" 
name="ctl00$ctl00$ASPxSplitter1$Content$ContentSplitter$MainContent$ASPxCallbackPanel1$ASPxFormLayout3$ASPxFormLayout3_E18" readonly="readonly" 
onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ctl00_ctl00_ASPxSplitter1_Content_ContentSplitter_MainContent_ASPxCallbackPanel1_ASPxFormLayout3_ASPxFormLayout3_E18')" 
onblur="aspxELostFocus('ctl00_ctl00_ASPxSplitter1_Content_ContentSplitter_MainContent_ASPxCallbackPanel1_ASPxFormLayout3_ASPxFormLayout3_E18')" value="Business" 
type="text" style="background-color: rgb(192, 224, 206);">
```

I've also tried empty/not empty method and it still doesn't work for some reason. It changes color to gray, but it doesn't change the background to white if it's not empty:

```
input[type="text"]:empty {
background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}

input[type="text"]:not(:empty) {
background-color : #FFFFFF; 
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp

Comment: This works for textarea, but the input text box doesn't work. I love these kinds of solution by the way.

Comment: `:empty` and `:blank` only selects elements without children, not with a value of an empty string

Comment: Hello, i saw you were still active on SO, i wonder if you found your solution for this case ? (i'll delete this comment later)

Answer (score 5):

You might  need the attribute `required` and the selector `:invalid`

```css
input[type="text"]:invalid, textarea:invalid {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" placeholder="write here"/>
<textarea required placeholder="write here"></textarea>
<hr/>
<input required type="text" placeholder="write here" value="text"/>
<textarea required placeholder="write here">text</textarea>
```

Comment: In DevExpress, placing required input will add an asterix to the input field, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

It could be done quite easily with jQuery, cross-browser of course.

```js
$(':input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('empty', this.value.length === 0);
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
input.empty, textarea.empty {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: This method only works for textarea for some reason. This is really strange, perhaps a webform/devexpress quirk

Comment: Should work fine with [**both**](https://jsfiddle.net/hvpf8uae/), but you could try using the selector `$('input, textarea')` instead

Comment: @adeneo is it possible to only change the background color for inputs for specific class name?

Comment: @RainMan - Sure, just do `$(':input.className')` and in CSS `input.className.empty` etc. where you replace `className` with whatever name you choose of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for `placeholder` in `input` and `textarea` or for `value` in `input` and `:focus` :

```css
[placeholder=""],
[value=""] {
  background: red;
}
[placeholder=""]:focus,
[value=""]:focus {
  background: none
}
```

```html
<h2>Placeholder</h2>
<input type="text" placeholder="" />
<textarea placeholder=""></textarea>
<hr />
<h2>Value</h2>
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: The problem with DevExpress controls is that there's no placeholder settings for input textbox. Question edited to include DevExpress input textbox.

Comment: @sojim2 I just updated answer as you wrote the comment, take a look, using placeholder or value is the same.

Comment: I tried with `input[value*=""] { background:red;}` but still no luck

Comment: see my code, it is not `input[value*=""]` but just `input[value=""]`. you are adding an extra `*`. Run my snippet

Comment: I tried your code in its entirety, still no luck. Using Chrome, DevExpress, Web Forms.

Comment: if you run the snippet you see that works, can you give a link?

Comment: This is an intranet application unfortunately. Let me get in touch with DevExpress, perhaps this is their controls specific problem. Thanks for the help!